# C# method Linq variable return

Tags: c#, linq, variables, methods

hope your help :)

I search to make the result of the LinQ Variable bellow "ES" available in an other method.

```
public void Contract_ES(QCAlgorithm Algorithm_ES, Slice slice)
{
    foreach(var chain in slice.FutureChains)
    {

    var ES = (from futuresContract in chain.Value.OrderBy(x => x.Expiry)
              where futuresContract.Expiry > Algorithm_ES.Time.Date.AddDays(1) 
              select futuresContract).FirstOrDefault();

    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. Your variable is evaluated multiple times. If you want to somehow return them from this method, you can create a list and return that list or yield return as enumerable. It depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded QuantConnect just to get an idea what you're trying to do. The example below should at least not yield any errors, but I haven't tried the output.

```
using QuantConnect.Data;
using System.Linq;
using QuantConnect.Data.Market;

namespace QuantConnect.Algorithm
{
    public interface IFuturesContractSelector_ES
    {
        FuturesContract GetFuturesContract_ES(QCAlgorithm Algorithm_ES, Slice slice);
    }
    public class Contract_ES : IFuturesContractSelector_ES
    {
        private readonly Slice _Slice;
        private readonly QCAlgorithm _Algorithm_ES;

        public Contract_ES(QCAlgorithm Algorithm_ES)
        {
            _Algorithm_ES = Algorithm_ES;
        }

        public Contract_ES(Slice slice)
        {
            _Slice = slice;
        }

        public FuturesContract GetFuturesContract_ES(QCAlgorithm Algorithm_ES, Slice slice)
        {

            foreach (var chain in slice.FutureChains)
            {
                if (chain.Value.Symbol.Value.StartsWith("ES"))
                {
                    return (from futuresContract in chain.Value.OrderBy(x => x.Expiry)
                              where futuresContract.Expiry > Algorithm_ES.Time.Date.AddDays(1)
                              select futuresContract).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could do an extension on the Slice class:

```
using QuantConnect.Data;
using System.Linq;
using QuantConnect.Data.Market;

namespace QuantConnect.Algorithm
{
    public static class SliceExtensions
    {
        public static FuturesContract GetFuturesContract_ES(this Slice slice, QCAlgorithm Algorithm_ES)
        {
            foreach (var chain in slice.FutureChains)
            {
                if (chain.Value.Symbol.Value.StartsWith("ES"))
                {
                    return (from futuresContract in chain.Value.OrderBy(x => x.Expiry)
                            where futuresContract.Expiry > Algorithm_ES.Time.Date.AddDays(1)
                            select futuresContract).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void TestMyMethod(Slice slice)
        {
            var contract = slice.GetFuturesContract_ES(new QCAlgorithm());

            //... do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for have checking directly on the platform, if you didn't know this site, i'am enjoy to discover it to you ! ;) Your solution works fine to implement the variable ES in an other method with Slice parameter, Now I want t introduce it in a method with no Slice parameter. How do I have to proceed ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Can you explain further what you mean by your next problem? Is it on FutureChains?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create an interface then the method, result is :

using QuantConnect.Securities;

```
namespace Quant
   {
    public interface IFuturesContractSelector_ES
    {
        void GetFuturesContract_ES(QCAlgorithm Algorithm_ES, Slice slice);
    }
   }

public class Contract_ES : IFuturesContractSelector_ES
{
    private readonly Slice _Slice;
    private readonly QCAlgorithm _Algorithm_ES;

    public Contract_ES(QCAlgorithm Algorithm_ES)
            {
                _Algorithm_ES = Algorithm_ES;
            }

    public Contract_ES(Slice slice)
            {
                _Slice = slice;
            }

public void GetFuturesContract_ES(QCAlgorithm Algorithm_ES, Slice slice)
    {

    foreach(var chain in slice.FutureChains)
        {
            if (chain.Value.Symbol.StartsWith("ES"))
            {
                var ES = (from futuresContract in chain.Value.OrderBy(x => x.Expiry)
                where futuresContract.Expiry > Algorithm_ES.Time.Date.AddDays(1) 
                select futuresContract).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    return ES;
    }
}
```

At the Line return ES, I get this error :
The name "ES" does not exist in the current context.

Weird because I have another method build in this way, with no prob -_-
Maybe using foreach statement that cause the non possible return of "var ES" ?

Comment: You declare ES inside of the if statement (var ES = (....)), you need to declare it above the foreach for this to work.

Comment: even if I do it, it's the same thing with the foreach state

Comment: Also, your GetFuturesContract_ES method is a void, but you are trying to return a contract. You need to change the return type of the method.

Comment: that was you expected ?

Comment: Well, if you hover your mouse over var ES, what does it say what type it is? That type should be the return type of your method, and the same in the interface.

Comment: nothing, am i right if I tell that I create "public string ES { get; private set; }" this will not be fill by "var ES" ?

Comment: See my separate answer